# Django Dyanmic form: presentation and information collections

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a complex form:

```
<<forms.py>>
class AttributeOptionForm(forms.Form):
    option_name = forms.CharField(label="Attribute Option")


class AttributeForm(forms.Form):
    attr_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label="Attribute Name")
    attr_options_list = [AttributeOptionForm(), AttributeOptionForm()]


class ProjectForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=250, label="Name")
    attr_form_list = [AttributeForm()]
```

ProjectFrom holds at least one AttributeForm (which may grow on runtime) and each AttributeForm holds at least two AttributeOptionForm (which may also grow on runtime). You may think of any AttributeForm as a question with multiple answers (AttributeOptionForm), which I want the user to fill in.

This is how I present the ProjectForm.

```
<<project_form.html>>
                       <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <span class="text-danger small">{{ form.name.errors }}</span>
                            </div>
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ form.name.label_tag }}</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">{{ form.name }}</div>
                        </div>
                        {% for attr_form in form.attr_form_list %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <span class="text-danger small">{{ attr_form.att_name.errors }}</span>
                            </div>
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ attr_form.attr_name.label_tag }}</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">{{ attr_form.attr_name }}</div>
                            {% for option in attr_form.attr_options_list %}
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                    <span class="text-danger small">{{ option.option_name.errors }}</span>
                                </div>
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ option.option_name.label_tag }}</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">{{ option.option_name }}</div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </form>
```

In the form, in addition, there are an 'add_attribute_option' buttons (per attribute), 'add_attribute' button, and 'submit' button.

1. How do I collect the data in my views.py file? in order to save in the appropriate Models
2. Is there a better way of collecting data from a dynamic form such as this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nicole Harris has this great tutorial which solved my problem by showing me how to use Formset. Thanks Nicole!
http://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html